# XSLT 3 : convert xml to json

Tags: xslt-3.0

When I am trying to convert XML to JSON using XSLT3
<xsl:copy-of select="xml-to-json($finalOutPut, map { 'indent' : false() })"/>

I get below error :
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: xml-to-json: element found in wrong namespace: Q{}wrapper

Basically i am converting one xml to another xml , renaming certain field.
Passing this xml as a input to xml-to-json() .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The XML format that `xml-to-json` consumes is specified both in the XSLT 3.0 specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json-to-xml-mapping) as well as in the XPath and XQuery 3.1 function specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#json.

Basically all elements need to be in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions` and are `map`, `array`, `string`, `boolean`, `number` etc., to reflect the JSON datatypes.

The error message suggests your input contains an element named `wrapper` in no namespace, so that is certainly not the right format for that function. You will need to use additional transformation steps to transform your XML to the one the function expects.

Comment: Thanks @Martin for the suggestion . For now  i am converting xml to json using a different library ..